# NodeJs: SetInterval stopping after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, setinterval, namecheap

I hosted my NodeJs app on a shared hosting. My server.js script looks like this:

```
...

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.send('Yep. Working!');
});


const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Interval is running')
        (some other code here)

    }, 1000 * 60 * 10 );
});
```

When I first run the app the `setInterval` works good for several hours but after several hours `setInterval` stops working and I did not get any kind of error anywhere. But if I go to base route (`https://localhost:8080`) the `setInterval` starts working again.

What might be the problem?

Comment: You're using a 10 minute interval... Why on earth are you using a _ten minute_ interval? O_o

Comment: I am watching a Telegram group in every 10 minutes for new messages @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: You should use node-schedule to be async.
This code will be an issue in production.

Comment: The shared host pushes your application to sleep mode.